# AWS-IoT Topic with $

Tags: aws-iot

How can I publish and subscribe on the topics that start with $ e.g in AWS-IoT:

`$shared/xy/1234`

I had read the:

1- [Topics AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/topics.html)

2- [Reserved topics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/reserved-topics.html)

When I add **$** to topic name, than I have the exception:

`c.a.s.i.c.m.AwsIotMqttMessageListener: Request failed for topic $share/xy/+/xyz`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been trying to use [shared subscription](https://www.hivemq.com/docs/hivemq/4/user-guide/shared-subscriptions.html) feature of MQTT 5 since the topic structure for shared subscriptions is *$share/GROUPID/TOPIC*

However, presently AWS does NOT support it, there has been a [request](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=757689) though.

Answer (score 1):

the "$" character is for topics that are reserved in AWS, you can't publish to a Topic that begins with that.